# Angular promise in a for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var  myArray = [{post:{message:"hi",user:"joe"}},{post:{message:"how are you",user:"bob"}}];
```

where `myArray[0].post.user = "joe"` and `myArray[1].post.user = "bob"`

I want to add another key (i.e. `comment`) to `post`dynamically based on an asynchronous call using $resource while looping through the array.

The remote `Comments` service works well and looks like this:

```
.factory('Comments',function($resource, myUrl) {
    var comments = $resource(myUrl + 'api/comments/:postId', {postId: '@id'});
    return comments;
})
```

in my controller

```
var  myArray = [{post:{message:"hi",user:"joe"}},{post:{message:"how are you",user:"bob"}}];

var messageCount = myArray.length;
var post_id = 1;   //comes from elsewhere

for (var c = 0; c < messageCount; c++) {

    Comments.get({postId:post_id}).$promise.then(function(comments) {
      console.log(comments);     //  <<---- objects appear to be fine in the console log
      myArray[c].post.comments = comments;  // <---- throws undefined error 

    });
 }
```

Why does `myArray.post.comments = comments` throw the error `Cannot set property 'user' of undefined` ??

Comment: If your log your `comments` from the promise, what does it display?

Comment: `Resource {  id:"1",comment:"This is my comment"  }`

Comment: You don't have a property `user` being set somewhere else?

Comment: The error message doesn't see to make sense regarding what's being done... If you could print both `comments` and `myArray[c].post` in each function you may have a better idea of what's going on. Or if that doesn't help, add the log to your post for us :)

Comment: Your error message would make sense on these lines --> myArray[0].post.user = "joe" and myArray[1].post.user = "bob" , but I would think it impossible for it to throw that error when trying to set .post.comments

Comment: Is it possible that Comment service tries to initialize myArray[c].post.comments before myArray has been created?

Comment: @lilbiscuit In that case, you would get a "cannot read property post of undefined" error

Comment: I guess your problem is related to the C variable: maybe your C variable (that is shared in your for loop) has gone "onward" when the "then" function is called.

Comment: @Luxor001  you're right.   C is always 2 in Comments.get.... that's it.

Comment: I'll post an answer with my own answer, so you can accept it and close the question.

Comment: It is worth noting that using the `Promise.all()` method would be better here if the promises are independent of  one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is related to the C variable: maybe your C variable (that is shared in your for loop) has gone "onward" when the "then" function is called.

*repost of a my comment that served as answer*

Comment: a solution would have been nice ;) I am going to push the results into a new array and then merge...hope that works.

Comment: My bad, i thought your "that's it" were, well, a "that's it" (the conclusion of your issue). feel free to post anything else or even post a new question of your issue.